# Como usar o template do django admin non meu formulário

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Estou aprendendo sobre site admin do Django e minha dúvida é:

Tenho tenho um modelForm e um dos campos é uma foreignKey e gostaria das opções de change, edit e delete como no template do django(aquele botão de "+"). Li sobre a documentação e descobri uma opção que é o inlineModelAdmin, porém não sei se estou fazendo corretamente pois meu template ainda não aparece os botões, se alguém poder me ajudar agradeço > Django 3.0 & Python3

**models.py:**

```
from django.db import models

class TypePoke(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    url = models.URLField()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Pokemon(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    size = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    order = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    typepoke = models.ForeignKey(TypePoke, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**admin.py:**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from pokedb.models import *

class PokeInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Pokemon  
    save_on_top = True  

   
class TypePokeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        PokeInline,
    ]

    save_on_top = True
 
    
admin.site.register(Pokemon)
admin.site.register(TypePoke, TypePokeAdmin)
```

**o formulario:**

```
{% extends 'admin/base_site.html' %}


{% block content %}
<form action="{% url 'pokedb:pokeform_post' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>

{% endblock content %}
```

o layout:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Viva no admin.py coloca só o seguinte.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from pokedb.models import *

admin.site.register(Pokemon)
admin.site.register(TypePoke)
```

Resultado, é este o esperado certo?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olá amigo, continua o mesmo display. Eu acho que não me expliquei mas o que quero é extender ou compartilhar esse template da sua imagem pro form.html da minha aplicação. Tava vendo a documentação e achei muito confuso, muitos detalhes. Em resumo o que quero é esse mesmo comportamento do formulário django admin(um botão de editar e criar) pra foreign key no form da minha aplicação. Não sei como fazer isso em nível de código, por isso tava pesquisando se tem como compartilhar esse template do django.

Comment: Sim, efetivamente entendi que querias no admin, como partilhaste o ficheiro admin.py. e para o fazer no admin, basta só isso. Se não é no admin, porque estás só a partilhar código do admin? Para o popup add tens aqui https://django-addanother.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html e para adicionar e adicionar/editar https://django-addanother.readthedocs.io/en/latest/edit-related.html

Comment: Sim exatamente esse popup que quero e não estava encontrando! Vou olhar. Muito obrigaado!